# can't accessing $_GET when use .htaccess url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

Now i want to cleanup my url with .htaccess
here is my .htaccess code

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /movies.php?id=$1&m=$2 [L]`

its working fine

here is 
movies.php

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['m'])) {
    header("Location:index.php");
} else {
    $m = str_replace('_',' ',$_GET['m']);
}
echo $_GET['m'];

?>
```

the problem is it every time redirect the page to index.php

Comment: `header("Location:index.php");` is what's redirecting you; what happens when you `print_r($_GET); die();` or `var_dump($_GET); die();` at the start of the file ?

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess should be

`RewriteRule ^movies/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?.html$ movies.php?m=$2&id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: Note the important part, the **QSA** flag. This means Query String Append; otherwise it is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the else part of the condition doesn't do anything except set the $m variable, but I don't see that being used somewhere else in your code. Did you maybe intend to do something like this?

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['m'])){  
    header("Location:index.php");  
} else {
    $m = str_replace('_',' ',$_GET['m']);  
}  

echo $m; ?>
```

Comment: I use $m in different place

Comment: the problem is it every time redirect the page to index.php

Comment: What do you enter in the address bar before it redirects to index.php?